# Font changing is not working on Edittext

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext, textview

I created a class for font named `Myfont`  its working fine on TextView but it's not working in EditText and Button.
here is my xml code

`<mypackagename.Myfont 
android:id="@+id/input_password"
android:hint="@string/hint_email" />`

Comment: put `EditText` class

Comment: post a code of Myfont  class. Anyway, what behavior do you want? Why do you have a whole class only for font?

Comment: Please post your whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to set the font programmatically:

`Edittext et = (Edittext) findViewById(R.id.appname);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/epimodem.ttf");
et.setTypeface(face);`

you can also change font of textview and button by this way.